# how to convert a video to images in c#?

Tags: c#, video

i have to convert a video to images i need some help to under stand this phenomenon and guid to code a program for it.

also

which format of video will be more useful for me ?

thanx in advance!

Comment: what the hell it this comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use FFMPEG in C# as a new child process (google search it how) to do all the work for you. It will work for every possible video codec, so you don't have to worry about how the frames are coded.

Also you can export frames to a couple of image formats, not just BMP.

Answer (score 0):

Try look here:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/directshownet/

I've never used it, but it could give you some hints (if not the solution itself)

Answer (score 0):

You can use VideoLan to the work for you, use Video Output module and set it to image [link](http://wiki.videolan.org/Video_Output)