# How to convert a video to an array of bitmaps?

Tags: c#, arrays, video, bitmap

I wish to be able to load a video and run Bitmap manipulations on it.
How can I either put the whole video in the memory, or get bitmaps frame by frame, manipulate them, then save to another stream or whatever.
Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the export have to be in C#?  If not, you should use ffmpeg (http://www.ffmpeg.org/).

Here is a similar question:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=564717

I've had great results with ffmpeg.

Comment: It must be in C#. I don't need to export them to files, I want to be able to get frames as Bitmaps for C# processing

Comment: There are free C# wrappers available: http://code.google.com/p/ffmpeg-sharp/, http://www.intuitive.sk/fflib/post/fflib-net-released.aspx, http://www.ffmpeg-csharp.com/

Comment: Well without using FFMPEG or any other Libraries (which i would recommend MainConcept) a simple solution cannot achieved .

Comment: ok. I got the idea. thank you.(Microsoft did a big libarary for everything except media edit. boo!)

Answer (score 0):

maybe this links help you.

[Working way to make video from images in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/539257/working-way-to-make-video-from-images-in-c)

[how to convert a video to images in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2855128/how-to-convert-a-video-to-images-in-c)

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/mediafoundationdevelopment/thread/7cf7014e-6537-480b-a052-65cbb929f449

Comment: It must be in C#. I don't need to export them to files, I want to be able to get frames as Bitmaps for C# processing